# Inserting elements at specific positions in an array in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list `A` containing a numpy array. I want to insert element `C1` at specific positions in `A` according  to `J`. But I am getting an error. I have included the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
J=[[4, 7, 10]]
C1=[0]

A=[np.array([10.                 ,  0.6382821834929432 ,  0.5928417218382795 ,
        0.5542698411479658 ,  0.6677634679746701 ,  0.8578897621707481 ,
        0.6544597670890333 ,  0.32706383813570833,  0.8966468940380192 ])]


A=np.insert(A[0],J,[C1],axis=1)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    A=np.insert(A[0],J,[C1],axis=0)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in insert

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4626, in insert
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: index array argument obj to insert must be one dimensional or scalar
```

The expected output is

```
A=[np.array([10.                 ,  0.6382821834929432 ,  0.5928417218382795 ,
         0.5542698411479658 ,  0, 0.6677634679746701 ,  0.8578897621707481 ,
         0, 0.6544597670890333 ,  0.32706383813570833,  0, 0.8966468940380192 ])]
```

Comment: The code your provided is not the same than in the error message. Do I get that right, you want to insert the value of C at the indices of J into A?

Comment: I have edited the post. Yes I want to insert the value of C at the indices of J into A. The expected output is above.

Comment: ok. there is no axis=1 in a 1D array. your array has length 9 (indices 0 to 8). it is not possible to insert something at position 10.

Comment: I have a list with many numpy arrays. I showed one so that I could understand how to insert at multiple locations.

Comment: Changed my answer back to the state you have, I thought I remove it because it was redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like this:

```py
import numpy as np

# need to take the indices based on the array before anything is inserted
J = [[4, 6, 8]]
C1 = [0]

A = [np.array([10.                 ,  0.6382821834929432 ,  0.5928417218382795 ,
        0.5542698411479658 ,  0.6677634679746701 ,  0.8578897621707481 ,
        0.6544597670890333 ,  0.32706383813570833,  0.8966468940380192 ])]

A = np.insert(A[0], J[0], C1[0])
```

Output `A`:

```
array([10.        ,  0.63828218,  0.59284172,  0.55426984,  0.        ,
        0.66776347,  0.85788976,  0.        ,  0.65445977,  0.32706384,
        0.        ,  0.89664689])
```

Notice that A is not a list with a `np.array` anymore, it is just the `np.array` now.

**EDIT**
insert one at a time with given indices.

```
J = [[4, 7, 10]]
C1 = [0]

A = [np.array([10.                 ,  0.6382821834929432 ,  0.5928417218382795 ,
        0.5542698411479658 ,  0.6677634679746701 ,  0.8578897621707481 ,
        0.6544597670890333 ,  0.32706383813570833,  0.8966468940380192 ])]

for elem in J[0]:
    A = [np.insert(A[0], elem, C1[0])]
```

Comment: This is fine but I want to use the same ```J=[[4, 7, 10]]``` I mention in the post. I think we will need to insert one element at a time.

Comment: yes, if this is mandatory then you can't insert them at once...index 10 is just not existent at the beginning.

Comment: That's right. I want ```J``` as  it is. Any idea how I can insert one at a time?